# WCF service error from WP8 app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a WP8 app that call some methods in my WCF service hosted in my IIS. 
If I restart the server, I receive an error when try to connect my service from my WP8.

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

The most interesting thing is: when I open my IE from my WP8 and type the address of the service, the page says: "You have created a service", meaning that the service is runnig and OK.

I figured out a way to access my service again: run my app from WP 8.1 emulator, connect to the service and after this is can access my service from my devices again!

Here is my app.config service:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Metadata" name="WCFDataLibrary.EnvioDados">
          <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBinding" contract="WCFDataLibrary.IEnvioDados" />
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="http://vm-2008-srv/WCFDataService/EnvioDados" />
              </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        <!--<identity>
          <dns />
        </identity>-->
      </service>
  </services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <!--<behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>-->
    <behavior name="Metadata">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://vm-2008-srv/WCFDataService/meta" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And here is my client ServicesReference.clientConfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnvioDados" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://10.120.186.164/WCFDataService/EnvioDados/basic"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IEnvioDados"
            contract="EnvioDadosService.IEnvioDados" name="BasicHttpBinding_IEnvioDados" />
    </client>
```

My app just need to access the intranet, this is why I'm using a private IP!

Why the hell I can't access my service from my client, just after access the service from my emulator ?

Regards